# Is it possible to use a task inside another task environment?

Tags: errors, tasks

I am trying to put a `task` inside another `task` environment (I am very impressed that nobody has asked this), but it does not work:

```
\begin{tasks}(1)
    \task Task a)
    \task Task b)
    \begin{tasks}(1)
        \task Task b)1 % or b)1)  ,  or b1)  ,  something like that.
    \end{tasks}
    \task Task c)
\end{tasks}
```

When I compile I have 7 errors.

---

Instead of that, I use the `inparaenum` environment. For example:

```
\begin{tasks}(1)
    \task Task a)
    \task Task b)

    \begin{inparaenum}[b1)]
        \item Item b1)
        \hfil
        \item Item b2)
        \\
        \item Item b3)
        \hfil
        \item Item b4)
    \end{inparaenum}
    \task Task c)
\end{tasks}
```

Note that between `\item Task b` and `\begin{inparaenum}[b1)]` I added a line break because if not, the text appears immediately after *Task b)*.

But if I run this code:

```
\begin{tasks}(1)
    \task Task a)

    \begin{inparaenum}[a1)]
        \item Item a1) % it says: 11) Item a1)
        \hfil
        \item Item a2) % it says: 22) Item a2)
        \\
        \item Item a3) % it says: 33) Item a3)
        \hfil
        \item Item a4) % it says: 44) Item a4)
    \end{inparaenum}
    \task Task b)
    \task Task c)
\end{tasks}
```

I get the following warning:

```
Package paralist Warning: Incorrect label; no or multiple counters.
(paralist)                The label is: a1) on input line 2435.
```

For that reason I do not want to work with the `inparaenum` environment, but yes with the `task` environment haha. I would like to work with a `task` within another `task`. Does anyone know if this is possible?

If not, I would like to solve the second problem.

Thanks!

**EDIT**:

I have this code now:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item 1.
    \item 2.
    \item 3.
    \begin{tasks}(1)
        \task a)
        {\begin{tasks}(2)
            \task a1)
            \task a2)
            \task a3)
            \task a4)
        \end{tasks}}
        \task b)
        \task c)
    \end{tasks}
    \item 4.
    \begin{tasks}(3)
        \task a)
        \task b)
        \task c)
    \end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

When I compile I get:

[image: Tasks and subtasks]

And a Bad Box's message:

```
Overfull \hbox (27.37506 too wide) in paragraph at lines 22--22
```

How could I fix those 2 errors?

Comment: You can avoid the compilation errors enclosing the subtask list between curly braces but that not solve others problems. Funnily  with your MWE  everything will seems correct with this patch, but try with the sublist in other position that  b) or with more than one column.

Comment: It's not possible. This is mentioned in the manual of the `tasks` package section 3.1: “the `tasks` environment cannot be nested.”

Comment: @Fran It does not work `:(`. If I have a many `item` and `task` items the `task` that is most out starts with `d)`, but the `subtasks` starts correctly: `a)`, `b)`, `c)` and `d)`. Are these the problems you were talking about?  Thanks.

Comment: @manooooh yes,  the counter goes crazy.  Split the main task in two o more columns does not work either if you force a subtasks in this way.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to nest a tasks environment in another tasks, but it can be nested in `enumerate`. As  your outer tasks has only one column, here is, hopefully, a solution with `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}

\settasks{counter-format =\alph{enumi}tsk[1]), label-width = 1.5em, before-skip = -1ex}
\begin{enumerate}[label = \alph*), wide, leftmargin = *, itemsep = 1ex, after = \setcounter{enumi}{0}]
    \item Task A
    \item Task B

  \begin{tasks}(2)
 \task Item b1)
 \task Item b2)
 \task Item b3)
 \task Item b4)
 \end{tasks}
    \item Task C \begin{tasks}(2)
 \task Item b1)
 \task Item b2)
 \task Item b3)
 \task Item b4)
 \end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I forgot to mention that there is a list above the `task` environment. If I put `\begin{enumerate}` and then `\item 1.` before `\begin{enumerate}[label = \alph*), wide, leftmargin = *, itemsep = 1ex, after = \setcounter{enumi}{0}]` the `task` list always says `a1)`, `a2)`, etc. in the two `tasks` environment you share. How could I fix that?

Comment: If  you have two levels of lists before, use `enumii` in the place of `enumi`, like this: `\setup{tasks}{counter-format =\alph{enumii}tsk[1]), ...}`.

Comment: What do you mean? I edited my message adding an example. I clarify that the `enumerate` list is **always one column**, but the main `task` (inside the `enumerate`) list could have more than one column, and the `task` inside the `task` list too.

Comment: @manooooh: I thought only the lowest level would have more than one column. I don't have time at the moment, I'll look at the problem  later if no one has found a solution. Maybe using a two-column environment for the intermediate level would solve it.

Comment: Ok, I will wait (no hurry `:)`).